# Dockerfile - Creating dockerfile

Tags: tomcat, docker, installation, dockerfile

I'm trying to pull tomcat from the Dockerfile I have created and pull centos using the command:

```
FROM centos
RUN docker run -it tomcat
```

Then now I'm creating a new Dockerfile, how do I pull the tomcat from the Dockerfile I've created above without pulling from the Docker Hub?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to build your Dockerfile into a docker image:

```
docker build -t my-custom-image .
```

Now you can base another docker container from the image you created, just like you were doing with `centos`:

```
FROM my-custom-image
```